# Rails initial page load extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastcgi, windows-server

I've got a rails app in development mode (3.1.12 ruby 1.9.2) running on a windows server via fastcgi (with heliconzoo).

If i wait a certain amount of time from page load to page load, it takes 4-6 seconds to load the page. Afterwards it's loading with normal speed independent on which computer and in every browser.

Does the app/service shutdown if nobody visits the page within a while?

What can I do to prevent this behaviour?

e: For the first entry of today the development.log says it took 500ms to load the page which is 10 times faster...But it took 5s to load actually...